# SQL Get the previous and next date even equal

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a field `date` and a query like :

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `my_table`"
        ." WHERE SOME_CONDITIONS"
            ." AND `n_date` IN(SELECT MIN(`n_date`) FROM `my_table` WHERE `n_date` > '2014-07-11')"
        ." LIMIT 1"
        .";";
```

With this query, I retrieve a data (with all field) with date just next to `2014-07-11`

If I have these datas in my database, with this query I retrieve the first `2014-07-15`

```
2014-07-15
2014-07-15
2014-07-11
2014-07-10
```

If you see my example, i have two lines with same dates `2014-07-15`, and if I try to get the element next to `2014-07-15`, my query doesn't work.

How can i do that ? Get the next element by Date, even if it's the same date. (But not the same ID ! )

Thanks !

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no concept of one row being "next to" another row, unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: We can use another colum : 'ref' for ordering ..

Comment: You do not need to add `;` two times

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal, One semicolon appears to be the end of the SQL statement, the other is the end of the php line.